# Grep in multiple files

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

I want to search for a pattern in a series of files, say, `log.2.gz`, `log.3.gz` ... `log.126.gz`. There are more similarly-named files in the same location (`log.127.gz` and so on), so I can't do a `zgrep log.*.gz`. I needed a pattern match for the file name too, which I was unable to accomplish.

I dumped all file names in which I have to perform the search into another file, say `file_list.txt`, which looks like this:

```
log.2.gz
log.3.gz
log.4.gz
.
.
.
```

Then I tried writing a bash script for searching in all files with names present in this file.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in $( cat file_list.txt )
    do
        echo $i 
        result=`zgrep 'xyz' $i`
        echo $result
    done
```

Looks like it is performing the search, but it is not dumping any output to screen, except the `echo $i`which prints out first file name.

Comment: The problem with the similarly-named files could be addressed by using brace expansion instead of filename expansion; for example, `log.{2..126}.gz` expands to `log.2.gz`, `log.3.gz`, ..., `log.126.gz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should be (untested):

```
while read i
do
    echo $i
    zgrep xyz $i
done < file_list.txt
```

**EDITED BELOW AFTER ACCEPTANCE**

In answer to your question about why your version doesn't work, that's because it is the equivalent of doing this, which won't work either:

```
for i in
log2.gz
log3.gz
log126.gz
do
  echo $i
  zgrep xyz $i
done
```

Comment: yes that works. But what would be wrong with the script that I wrote? Even if I just write `zgrep 'xyz' $i` after `echo $i`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Or just `xargs -a file_list.txt zgrep 'xyx'`

Comment: By the way, you may want to add `-H` option to zgrep so it tells you the names of the matching files.